# How to use image jpg with numpy.load()

Tags: numpy, google-colaboratory, pyhook

I try to implement [this code](https://github.com/MishaLaskin/rad/blob/master/Data%20Aug%20Visualization.ipynb), using colab:

```
x = np.load('data_sample.npy',allow_pickle=True)
stacked_x = np.concatenate([x,x,x],1)
stacked_x.shape
```

but my sample was an image in jpg format, so I wasn't able to convert these images to .npy to use it.

actually, I tried this code:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.asarray('image.JPG')


print(array.tobytes())
print(array)

x = np.load(array,allow_pickle=True)
stacked_x = np.concatenate([x,x,x],1)
stacked_x.shape
print(x)
```

but I got:
[image]

and when I use this code :

```
    x = np.load(array.tobytes(),allow_pickle=True)
```

I got:[image]

so, any suggestion to solve this, precisely to convert .jpg to .npy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what your code does:

```
In [57]: np.asarray('image.JPG')
Out[57]: array('image.JPG', dtype='<U9')
In [58]: np.asarray('image.JPG').tobytes()
Out[58]: b'i\x00\x00\x00m\x00\x00\x00a\x00\x00\x00g\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00J\x00\x00\x00P\x00\x00\x00G\x00\x00\x00'
```

That's just playing with the string.  It's not doing anything with a file named "image.JPG".  You need to use some sort of `image` processing package to first load the file, converting it from the compressed format to a 3d array.

`np.load` is used to load a file that was created by `np.save('file.npy')`.  It doesn't make sense to give that `array` variable as the file name.  It won't load a `jpg` file.

```
np.load('file.npy',allow_pickle=True)
```